# iPhone - NSDate formatting : strange values for times and timezones

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, datetime, time

I tested those calls :

```
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSDate date]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSDate convertToUTC:[NSDate date]]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSDate date] stringValueWithFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSDate convertToUTC:[NSDate date]] stringValueWithFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"]);

+ (NSDate*) convertToUTC:(NSDate*)sourceDate {
    [NSTimeZone resetSystemTimeZone];
    NSTimeZone* currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    NSTimeZone* utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];

    NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
    NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
    NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = gmtOffset - currentGMTOffset;

    NSDate* destinationDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval sinceDate:sourceDate] autorelease];     
    return destinationDate;
}
- (NSString*) stringValueWithFormat:(NSString*)formatRetour {
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatRetour];

    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self];
}
```

They give me :

```
2011-08-17 13:03:58 +0000
2011-08-17 11:03:58 +0000
20110817150358
20110817130358
```

On my phone, all configured to France/French, it's now : 15:03:58.

I don't understand the conversions that are done here.

1 gives me the real time at GMT
2 gives me something I don't understand...
3 gives the real time on the phone
4 gives the real time at GMT

I'm lost... From where does 2 comes ? How does those calls work ?
I mean, [NSDate date] gives 13:03 whith a +0000 timezone. Why formatting it shows 15:03 ?
Why 1 and 2 show a +0000 timezone, but different times ?

Could you guide me through this ?

Comment: I can't seem to find `convertToUTC`. Is it a category method?

Comment: @Akshay : Yes, my fault. Question edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSLog` will always print the description of the date object with a +0000 timezone.

When you use a `NSDateFormatter` to get a string from your date, it will use the timezone of your phone. With `"yyyyMMddHHmmssZZZ"` you would have got `20110817150358+0200`.

It's the same thing for the date you convert to UTC: you get 11:03 for GMT+0 (NSLog) which is the same as 13:03+0200 (using NSDateFormatter).

Yet `convertToUTC:` is buggy since the value should be 13:03+0000.

NSDate to NSDate conversion methods don't make sense. `NSDate` holds an absolute time and does not care about timezones. You only have to take timezones into account when doing NSString from/to NSDate conversions.

That's why when you "convertToUTC" 15:03+0200 you get 13:03+0200 which is the same as 11:03+0000.

A method like `- (NSString *)UTCRepresentation` would make sense though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be confused by the `NSLog` output. NSLog also needs a formatter to display `[NSDate date]` correctly. When you factor that in it should all make sense.